# How can the same subdirectory be removed from different parent directories?

Tags: linux, command-line

Assuming the following file structure:

```
/Parent1/
/Parent1/SubA/
/Parent1/SubB/
  ...
/Parent2/
/Parent2/SubA/
/Parent2/SubB/
  ...
```

what command can I use to recursively remove SubB from each parent directory? What I've been doing is long hand (very lame, but I'll include it just so it is clear what I'm trying to do):

```
rm -rf Parent1/SubB
^1^2^
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the `find` and `xargs` commands. Let's say *Parent1* and *Parent2* are both stored in a directory named *SuperParent*. You could do something along the lines of:

```
find /SuperParent -name SubB -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

This pipes a list of directories named SubB found below /SuperParent into the `xargs` command, which takes each directory and runs `rm` with the directory as an argument.

Comment: run `find /SuperParent -name SubB -type d | xargs echo rm -rf` first to echo what would be executed, if you're concerned.  Also, if you have way too many directories, you may get an error, so you'd have to do `find /SuperParent -name SubB -type d | xargs -i rm -rf {}` (which executes each rm command one at a time)

Comment: This almost worked for what I needed, and did send me down the right path. The only problem that I can see is that if there is a directory named SubB which is a child of SubA, (or a sibling of Parent1) and you did not want to delete that directory. Qualifying this with `code`find /SuperParent -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name SubB -type d | xargs rm -rf`code` seems like it would take care of that problem. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Ah that's a good point. Nice fix!

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many ParentX:

```
rm -rf Parent*/SubB
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! And it's so simple, and easy to remember! Thanks!

Comment: @slhck It works for me if file names have spaces in them. Please provide an example where it does not work.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected. Don't know why this was downvoted anyway.